# Как стилизовать родительський элемент в CSS?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть такая структура радио кнопок:

```
<label class="radio-btn">
  <input type="radio" />
 <span>
  <em>
   TEXT
  </em>
 </span>
</label>
```

И такие стили:

```
radio-btn{
    padding: 3px 20px 3px 20px;
    color: $gray60;
    
    input:checked {
      background-color: $gray10;
      color: red;
      font-weight: 500;
    }


    &:hover {
      background-color: $gray10;
      color: $purple80;
    }
  }
```

У меня не получается сделать стили для `label` когда инпут в статусе `checked`. Как это можно сделать?

UPD: Менять структуру нельзя, т.к кнопок в проекте тысячи и это сломает очень много всего. JS также использовать не рекомендовано

Comment: в css вы не сможете это сделать. только js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При желании, любое необходимое визуальное оформление здесь можно сделать по селектору `input:checked + span`

```css
label {
  position: relative;
}

label>span {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #eee;
  width: max-content;
  padding: 0.3em 0.5em 0.3em 1.5em;
}

label:hover>span {
  color: blue;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

input:checked+span {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<label class="radio-btn">
  <input type="checkbox" />
 <span>
  <em>
   TEXT
  </em>
 </span>
</label>
```

Comment: Да, самостотельно дошёл к такому же решению, поэтому закрываю вопрос и отмечаю этот ответ, как наиболее подходящий под эту ситуацию.

Answer (score 0):

в `label` помещаете `input` и `span`. `input` скрываете, а для `span` пишете стили. при `input:cheked`, меняете их. и `span` будет работать как `input`. `label` естесственно не стилизуете